# Best practice for exposed fields in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, visibility

I have often the problem that I want to use a mutable class inside, but I don't want to expose the mutable interface. Here are two samples:

```kotlin
class Sample {
    val listData: List<Any> = mutableListOf()
    val liveData: LiveData<Any> = MutableLiveData()

    fun updateFields() {
        // update both fields above: The add() and postValue() methods are not visible here
    }
}
```

I'm casting the fields sometimes other times I use private extension functions/properties. In rare cases I also used two fields one private with the mutable interface and the public with the immutable interface. The first two options feel very hacky and look ugly the last one with the second property feels very redundant and like the "normal" java boilerplate.

Another option would be to define an interface where just the implementation has the mutable fields, but that is again boilerplate which I want to avoid. How do you handle this?

Comment: Having two properties, the mutable type private and the immutable type public, is the normal solution, I believe. Looks like [they're trying to address this use case](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/explicit-backing-fields-re/proposals/explicit-backing-fields.md), however.

Comment: @Slaw, ugh, it seems that feature is going to take quite a while because of how many complicated considerations there are now that they're expanding it to be a replacement of backing properties with direct private field access instead of just syntactic sugar for defining a backing property.